# VBNET: How can I group a list of objects, and combine some properties as an array?

Tags: sql, vb.net, list, linq, class

I have a SQL database containing different values: **name, dimension, weight, price and material**.

Each product can have multiple materials.
as in the example below: product 1 has **3 materials**, and product 2 has **2 materials**.

| Name | Dimension | Weight | Price | Material |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 340 | 3.0 | 23.55 | Steel |
| Product 1 | 340 | 3.0 | 23.55 | Brass |
| Product 1 | 340 | 3.0 | 23.55 | Copper |
| **Product 2** | 214 | 2.3 | 13.25 | Steel |
| **Product 2** | 214 | 2.3 | 13.25 | Gold |

The thing I want to achieve now, is to group this data by name, and combine all materials into an array of materials.

**NOTE:** There is a new sql record added for each material, but the name, dimension, weight and price stay the same in these rows. (only the material changes)

```
    Public Class Product
      Public Property name As String
      Public Property dimension As Integer
      Public Property weight As Double
      Public Property price As Double
      Public Property materials() As String
    End Class
```

What I have tried so far:

```
    Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data source 
       =db;Initial Catalog=ProductData;Integrated 
       security=True")
       Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Product_data_db", 
       conn)
       Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
       adapter.Fill(table)
    End Using

Dim products As List(Of Product) = table.AsEnumerable().
Select(Function(x) New Product(x)).
GroupBy(Function(x) x.name).
Select(Function(y) New Product With 
{.name = y.Key, .materials = y.Select(Function(x) x.materials()}).ToList
```

**Expected result:**

a list(Of Product) containing 2 items:

**Item 1:**

- name  = "Product 1"
- dimension = 340
- weight = 3.0
- price = 23.55
- array of string containing the materials = Steel, Brass, Copper

**Item 2:**

- name  = "Product 2"
- dimension = 214
- weight = 2.3
- price = 13.25
- array of string containing the materials = Steel, Gold

Comment: What is `table`? A typed DataTable or is this really Linq-To-Sql/Linq-To-Entities? Btw, why you don't have a foreign-key to that product? I guess the table is `ProductMaterial` which is linked to `Product`, at least it should be so.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hi Tim, I added the code to my post.
I fill a table using a SqlDataAdapter, I don't know if that is the best way. If you know a better way, please let me know!

Comment: Normalize your data per Tim's advice (and use EF; it does this for you)

Comment: @CaiusJard Hi CaiusJard, can you tell me what EF stands for? I never heard of it :)

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: I've been trying to find a reasonable EFCore tutorial for VB.net but haven't turned anything up.. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53887.entity-framework-core-3-windows-forms-vb-net.aspx is OK, but in essence there isn't a tool that generates classes from DB tables, into VB.net directly - I'd recommend following a C# tutorial then running the C# through a converter to get the VB (it's just basic model classes and method calls so should work out fine), or compile the C# to a DLL and reference it from VB (you can have the VB and C# in the same solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually you are using ADO.NET to load the whole table into memory(a `DataTable`). That's ok if it will not grow but it's not a scalable approach. However...

You can use `GroupBy`, for example on this ValueTuple containing the product-fields:

```
Dim products As List(Of Product) = table.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(row) (Name:=row.Field(Of String)("Name"), Dimension:=row.Field(Of Int32)("Dimension"), Weight:=row.Field(Of Decimal)("Weight"), Price:=row.Field(Of Decimal)("Price"))).
    Select(Function(g) New Product With
    {
        .name = g.Key.Name,
        .dimension = g.Key.Dimension,
        .weight = g.Key.Weight,
        .price = g.Key.Price,
        .materials = g.Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("Material")).ToArray()
    }).
    ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now! I have been trying to get this result for over 6 hours now :D
     

Instead of loading everything into memory, how would you do it?